# Python: implement a "software-wide" setting that does not change often without running an if statement in every loop

Tags: python, settings, global

I want Python to kind of ignore a statement that is unlikely to be called in a function that is often called.

I do not have a formal education in programming, so please excuse my lackluster ability to desribe things. I will try to explain the concept by example.

Say I am writing a video game, first-person shooter, drawing 60 frames per second.
In the settings menu, the user can select whether or not to display the name of other players above their head. If they disable this, I store this value as `showplayernames = False`.

Then in my drawing function that outputs the graphics I have:

```
def draw():
    #code that draws the graphics on screen
    if showplayernames:
        #code that draws the name of players on screen
```

I call this function 60 times a second, but there is absolutely no point for checking if showplayernames is True 60 times a second. It will not change that often, in fact I could make this a kind of "constant" during play by preventing it to change. If showplayernames is False, then the third and fourth lines of the code are completely redundant, but they are executed nevertheless. The computer isn't smart enough to know it can ignore it, and there is a performance difference: reading a value and then checking if it is false takes time.

I could write two copies of the game (or at least the draw() function), one with only the first two lines when the user selects not to show names in the settings, and another without the if statement, and then run the appropriate one.

```
def draw_with_names():
    #code that draws the graphics on screen
    #code that draws the name of players on screen

def draw_without_names():
    #code that draws the graphics on screen
```

Although looping through either of these 60 times a second is more efficient than running `draw()` ,this is obviously not the way to go. There are dozens of settings like this.

So how do software and game designers implement these kind of "software-wide" settings efficiently?

Comment: Yes, for every additional statement there is a performance difference. But: Does it matter? Did you measure it? And how did you get the idea that the lines under the `if` statement are executed even if the the value evaluates to `False`?

Comment: Function pointers might help here: `draw_function = draw_with_names if showplayernames else draw_without_names` Then in the loop just call `draw_function()`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Nice idea. But if we have 10 different settings we really don't want to write 1024 different versions of the function.

Comment: @Matthias Yes. At that point a list of function pointers might work. Add/remove functions based on settings then call each function in the list in the main loop.

Comment: Side note: if you want to ask actual game developers how they handle this (I am not one): [gamedev.se].

Comment: @Matthias, before asking I did test it with a very simple function and there if a 10% difference in execution time between `return 2+3` and `if False: whatever; return 2+3`. Game graphics are obviously more complicated than that, but there are also more conditions, many of which become redundant to check.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp brilliant! Could accept as answer too. Create draw() and draw_names(), create a list with the functions I want to execute, then add/remove draw_names() from the list based on the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a game developer, but here's one option. Create a list of function pointers and add or remove from the list based on settings. Example:

```
def draw_player_names():
    # Code to overlay names

def draw_fps():
    # Code to overlay fps

def draw():
    # Main code to draw a frame of the game

# Hold all the functions to call
optional_funcs = []
if showplayernames: optional_funcs.append(draw_player_names)
if show_fps: optional_funcs.append(draw_fps)

# Main game loop
while True:
    draw()
    for f in optional_funcs: f()
```

This can be extended for any number of functions/options.

Answer (score 0):

not an game designer, but here is my voice.
You could store settings inside json file next to you python, but then you need to cover reading, getting right values etc.

You could use Environment variables to store value but that would end up using still "if" in the code.

Game designers use triggers and events to get things done, and on the lowest level I would assume those things also use if's.

system-wide-settings will in the end be used with if's

You could use overwrites based on event/trigger and use "same" draw function in both times but that only complicates code, and we all know to "keep it simple".

Sorry if this is not the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthias said, you shouldn't really bother about this kind of optimization. Look at these two very silly functions:

```
def lot_of_ifs(settings):
    #do something
    a=2**10
    b=2**10
    c=2**10
    for setting in settings:
        if setting:
            #do something more
            a=2**10
            b=2**10
            c=2**10

def no_ifs():
    #do something
    a=2**10
    b=2**10
    c=2**10

timeit("lot_of_ifs([0,0,0,0,0])", globals=globals())
0.2630380000000514

timeit("no_ifs()", globals=globals())
0.10232830000040849
```

The cost of creating a list, looping over it, and executing five `if`s is about 0.16 seconds for *one million* iterations, or *160 nanoseconds* per iteration, while at 60 fps you have *16.6 million nanoseconds* to execute your code.

Comment: The example was just to explain the concept. I do realize that if you have million other things to calculate, then adding a redundant boolean check here and there has negligible performance effect. It has been bugging me for a long time how to change contents of a loop dynamically, which is probably a better way to phrase my question.

Comment: Ok, then the brilliant answer by Johnny Mopp is perfect :)